# Problem enabling Livepatch

Tags: canonical-livepatch

I tried enabling Canonical Livepatch, according to the tutorial here: https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/client/enabling .
But, I repeatedly encountered the following error:

```
Stderr: Could not retrieve client information.: unauthorized

Stdout: 
Unable to enable Livepatch: Failed running command '/snap/bin/canonical-livepatch enable <REDACTED>' [exit(1)]. Message: Could not retrieve client information.: unauthorized
```

I already have my machine attached to Ubuntu Pro, which, as mentioned, includes Canonical Livepatch.
I closed (by pressing "X") my Canonical Livepatch Client earlier and, now, cannot find a way to re-enable it. I have Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Please help!

**Update:**

Just to inform you, I managed to enable LIvepatch, so everything is ok, but any additional help will be valuable.

Check here: [Can't enable Canonical Livepatch on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271580/cant-enable-canonical-livepatch-on-ubuntu-20-04-1-lts)

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop when you got it fixed! It would be great if you could elaborate on what you did, so others may benefit.

Comment: @user535733 Here you are!