# Livepatch Will Not Enable for Ubuntu 18.04 with "Could not retreive client information" error

Tags: server, proxy, canonical-livepatch

I have installed and set up Ubuntu Pro on my primary server and my backup server. However, I cannot get livepatch to enable on the backup server. I get the following error:

```
# sudo pro enable livepatch
One moment, checking your subscription first
Stderr: Could not retrieve client information.: GET request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/<machine-id>/info" failed

Stdout:
Unable to enable Livepatch: Failed running command '/snap/bin/canonical-livepatch enable <REDACTED>' [exit(1)]. 
Message: Could not retrieve client information.: 
GET request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/<machine-id>/info" failed
```

The backup server does not have an external internet connection itself and instead has a proxy set up on the primary server which it uses (using tinyproxy). I have set up the proxy for environment, apt and snap. All other functions work fine, and esm-apps and esm-infra are enabled and working. But I can't figure out how to get livepatch enabled.

I tried following the instructions given in [Can't enable Canonical Livepatch on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271580/cant-enable-canonical-livepatch-on-ubuntu-20-04-1-lts), however, this did not resolve the problem.

What an I missing?